# laravel image upload - ajax do not post my image file

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, image-upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload an image from an ajax call to my server (on laravel).

This is my server code:

```
if (Input::hasFile('flyer')){
    Log::info('WORK!');
    $file = Input::file('flyer');
    $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

As you can see, I've set a log istruction to understand if my file was uploaded or not...but my log file say it's not...

My form code:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'new_event', 'id' => 'newEvent', 'files' => true)) }}
    //some fields...
    {{ Form::file('flyer', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'inputImage')) }}
    // some other fields
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and here is my ajax call:

```
$('#newEvent').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#content').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Finally here my post-data (from google dev console) when i post my form:

```
_token:bqyiuQwtYEEs0tvhBcndi4ylsVPPi2FpYhGPLxKQ
title:sdfgsdf
description:sdfgsdf
activated_at:23/04/2015
expire_on:24/04/2015
contact:a name
phone:+387646
email:some@one.com
push:1
```

As you can see there is no trace of my image file (flyer)...why?

Comment: You better use [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Comment: Seems very interesting and maybe I'll need this for my next functionality...but since K.Toress answer do the trick, for now, I postpone the implementation of that library. Thanks to you and all the SO comunity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant submit a image like this, you need `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, try the below code.

```
$('#newEvent').submit(function() {

    // need to get form data as below
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#content').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why would you ever write `$(this)[0]` instead of just `this`?